# Some LGPOs for MS Edge do not apply for new users

Tags: registry, microsoft-edge, gpo

Good day!

I'm preparing the PowerShell script for applying some LGPOs in registry for computers that non domain joined. All of them applied successfully except several:

DefaultSearchProviderEnabled
DefaultSearchProviderSearchURL
DefaultSearchProviderName
SmartScreenEnabled
SmartScreenPuaEnabled

Here is what how it looks in registry:

[LGPO registry settings for Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vserq.png)

Interestingly! The script was run with admin rights on normal user session. Above settings successfuly applied for for this only user. All other users in PC including admin didn't applied them.

During the search in internet i found this: "This policy is available only on Windows instances that are joined to a Microsoft Active Directory domain". But why these settings applied for the user on which session the script was ran?? Is it possible to apply for all others without joining the domain?

User with applied settings:

[Applied LGPO settings in Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAGO2.png)

All other users on the same PC for whom settings did not apply:

[Not applied LGPO settings in Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se9Lj.png)

Comment: These policies can also be applied to Windows 10 Pro, or Enterprise instances enrolled for device management. Does your device meet these requirements?

Comment: I would also like to know what your OS is. Mine is Windows 10 Enterprise 21H1, and I can reproduce this issue.

Comment: My OS is Windows 11 Pro and i test with 1 laptop and 1 desktop. However, i did not connect them to the domain.

Comment: Also, you told: "enrolled for device management." Do you mean - AD joined? 
As i searched in google a little bit, i understood that it is different right?... Is it possible to use in my case and to deceive the system, so that it things it is managed?

Comment: Yes, they are different. You said "deceive the system", but I don't think it is a "deception" if you try to meet the requirements. BTW, do you have any work or school account that is connected to this "only user"? It may have something to do with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you have to be either AD-joined or enrolled for device management to apply those specific group policies. Looks like this "only user" has been joined to AD domain or enrolled for device management, but you just haven't realized it.

Pay attention to those **work or school accounts**, if any, that are connected to this "only user". I reproduced this issue, but today I've realized that I had one **AD-joined work account** connected so that I could apply those specific group policies to this user but failed on others.

Comment: This is true in my case. After i added AD joined account to work or school accounts, this policy started to work! 
I did not realize that this kind of account affects the policy.
Thank you very much!

Comment: @Alex You're welcome. Glad to see the problem resolved.